# Change dates of default "quarter" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Is there any way of changing the "default start and end dates", of what is interpreted as the "quarters" in Pandas / Numpy? I've looked through the docs and tried reading the pandas source-code, but with no results to show for it.

```
import pandas as pd
date_range = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2021-01-01')
df_dates = pd.DataFrame({'dates' : date_range}, index = date_range)
print(df_dates['dates'].dt.quarter.drop_duplicates())
```

Results in these "start dates" of the quarters.

```
2020-01-01    1
2020-04-01    2
2020-07-01    3
2020-10-01    4
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```

So I want to change these to different dates, if possible. As a "saved offset" that lives in the "current session"...

Desired output would be something like this, on the dt.quarter-accessor (if pushed one month ahead.)

```
2020-02-01    1
2020-05-01    2
2020-08-01    3
2020-11-01    4
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```

Comment: How do you want to compute your quarter based on given date?

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Preferably I would want to use the dt.quarter accessor to interpret dates to different ranges. Dependent on the "setting" set in pandas.

Comment: @CarlF.Corneil please post an example expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean by?

```
print(df_dates['dates'].dt.quarter.drop_duplicates().shift(1, freq='MS'))
```

Output:

```
2020-02-01    1
2020-05-01    2
2020-08-01    3
2020-11-01    4
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```